# I think I am messing up the scope of these pointers, C++?

Tags: c++, memory, scope

So this is a reduced version of my main / Initializer function. When I call it and it has to add any items to the players inventor, I get a Debug Assertation Failed error.

It seems to me like I am mixing up the scope somewhat?
Am I declaring something new inside the scope of the function, and then not being able to access it again out in main?
I tried a few things inside the function, like using Getters/Setters instead of assigning is completely, like `p_player = p` but I don't think that actually deals with the problem at all, and I'm kind of confused.

```
int main()
{
    Array<Item> items(3);
    string itemsfilename = "itemsfile.txt";
    Initializer::InitializeItems(items, itemsfilename);

    Login login;
    Player p1;
    string filename = login.LoginToGame();
    Initializer::InitializePlayer(p1, rooms, items, 3, filename);
}  

void Initializer::InitializePlayer(Player& p_player, HashTable<string, Room>& p_rooms, Array<Item>& p_items, int p_numItems, std::string& p_filename)
{
    ifstream playerfile(p_filename);

    int inventorycount = 0;

    //all the stuff needed to make a player
    std::string name;
    int health;
    int confidence;
    int humor;
    int speed;
    std::string room;
    Room* currentRoom;
    Inventory inventory(100);

    //reading in values from file

    for(int i = 0; i < inventorycount; i++)
    {
        playerfile.getline(value, 256);
        std::string item(value);
        for(int j = 0; j < p_numItems; j++)
        {
            if(p_items[j].GetName() == item)
            {
                inventory.AddItem(&(p_items[j]));       //This line taken out, removes the error.
            }
        }
    }

    Player p(name, health, confidence, humor, speed, currentRoom, inventory);
    p_player = p;
}
```

AddItem() takes a pointer to an item, and then appends it to it's DLinkedList.

Edit:
The error I get is
Debug Assertation Failed!

Program: zzz
File f:\dd/vctools/crt_bld/self_x86/crt/src/dbgdel.cpp
Line: 52

Expression: _Block_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

AddItem() Code:

```
bool AddItem(Item* p_item)
{
    if(p_item->GetWeight() + m_weight <= m_maxWeight)
    {
        m_inventory.Append(p_item);
        m_weight += p_item->GetWeight();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: On what line does it assert? What is the error message? Not immediately clear from your post.

Comment: Explain the "Debug Assertion Failed" in a little more detail. What's the error message? What assertion is failing? What test is making it fail?

Comment: Since `inventory.AddItem(...)` is (apparently) causing the problem, it would probably help to have that line added to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so we still don't have the code that actually causes the problem, but I'm pretty certain I know what's going on, and to avoid getting into a "20 questions of add more code" - there's two possible scenarios:

1. Items is an array of objects, and you store pointers to them in your `m_inventory` container. When destroying this container, the objects are destroyed by calling `delete` on the items - which doesn't work since the content is not allocated from the heap.
2. When you copy the `inventory` the `m_inventory` container is not appropriately copied, and the contents fall apart because the pointers to the storage is failing.

If this doesn't help, then please try to reduce your code to something that only shows this problem, without using files that we don't know the content of and can be posted as a complete program in the question with all the code necessary [remove any other code that isn't needed], so we can see EVERYTHING. Currently, we're only seeing a few bits of the code, and the problem is almost certainly DIRECTLY in the code you've shown us.

Comment: So it sounds like #1 from what I can tell?  The m_inventory uses an internal DoublyLinkedList, who's destructor uses `delete itr`where itr is a pointer to a node(containing the Item pointer) as you said. The Array of objects in the first place is made using `m_array = new Datatype[p_size]` and then `delete[]m_array;`. I'm not quite sure what the problem is after that, or how to solve it though. Thanks btw

Comment: Yes, if you are using `delete itr;` then you need to use `new` to create the object in the first place.